Database Engine Tuning Advisor in Azure
We have several performance issues, which I think could be mitigated by proper indices, better queries or even partitioning as some tables have over 1B records.
I was hoping to use Database Engine Tuning Advisor, as I would do on my local copy of the DB in my previous roles, but seems it does not work in Azure, instead the suggestion, I understand, is to use Performance recommendations in Azure's console.
But all I could find there were two recommendations for two very small tables.
Can one advise on what is the best tool to perform Azure SQL DB analysis, please?
Any advise on best practices for Azure SQL DB analysis will also be greatly appreciated.

Database Engine Tuning Advisor is not supported on any flavor of Azure SQL Database (DTU-model, vCore-model, Hyperscale, Managed Instance, Serverless). However, Azure SQL can help you to automatically create needed indexes and drop unneeded indexes if you enable Automatic Tuning on your Azure SQL Database.
On Azure Portal, left panel vertical menu, select Automatic Tuning.

Then configure Automatic Tuning to use artificial intelligence for creating and removing indexes of the database based on the database workload created by applications.

Remember to make a click on the Apply button once you have made these changes.

Thank you @Alberto.

Realised was too quick with Add button. We have Force Plan on, but I don't want create / drop scripts executed automatically. Is it possible to have a report with those recommendations? I cannot find any option yet.

@BOR15K Please read my answer on this StackOverflow forum thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595197/is-there-a-way-to-script-out-all-indexes-created-by-azure-automatic-tuning-in-mu/55623816#55623816
